# Why is there unrelated SQL script in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SSMS and cloning tables with same structure by using "script table as->create -> new query window".

My database have around 100 tables and my main task is to to perform data archiving by creating a clone table (same constraint,index,triggers,stats as old table) and importing certain data i want from the old table to new table.

My issue is inside the generated script say I want to clone table A , and in the script, there are sql scripts like { create table for table B} , {create table for table K}, etc along with their index and constraint scripts. Therefore, it  makes the whole script very tedious and long.

I just want to focus on table A script so i can clone it and insert the relevant data into it . I know it has something to do with my options setting but I am unsure which options I should set to True for scripting, if i just want to clone table with same constraint,columns,indexes,triggers and stats. Does anyone know why there are unrelated script and how do i fix it ?

Comment: archive using a different database... create a backup and restore to the archive database server .. run ETL over SSIS with truncate in the archive database... that's your clone

Comment: The thing is i need to clone certain tables only, not all the tables in t he database.

Comment: yup.. just drop the tables you don't want.

Comment: I meant i want the tables but only want to clone certain tables.

Comment: If you are **really** using the "script table as" option, then the generated script should only have statements specific to that table. Are you using the "tasks->generate scripts" option by right-clicking on the database?

Comment: Nope, I am aware of that method as well. These two methods are actually very similar, if you use task generate scripts to specific table and choose to script "Schema and data" ,we get the data in the clone table as well but i only want specific data from old data into new table, which is why i think my way is better?